# New Italian Citizen entered EU over 6 months ago, still waiting for Italian passport, need to leave the EU. Can I do this?

Tags: citizenship, eu, passport, dual-citizenship

I entered the EU on December 26, 2020 with my Spanish partner under the approval of the Spanish consulate as a family member with my American Passport Name 1. Upon entering Spain I applied for and received recognition as the legally registered partner of a Spanish person (paraje de hecho) which gives me 5 years of living in Spain. I also registered my empadronamiento locally in Barcelona - all done with **passport name 1**.

In March, I had Passport with name 1, which I entered Spain on replaced in prep for my citizenship application in Italy, to **Passport Name 2** - - married names vs maiden names.

Late March - Early June - in Italy. Upon entry to Italy, I declared my presence to the polizia, I applied for permiso de soggiorno (still waiting for it to be approved), registered my residency, applied for and obtained citizenship.

Late June - my citizenship to Italy has been established and the name for all documents and the **new passport will be name 3 but the passport is not ready - Italy is on a backlog of passports and they are taking a lot of time to complete.

Here is my question, I need to return quickly to the USA due to a family emergency. I've contacted the Italian quatora to inquire about my new passport, it is not ready and they cannot tell me when it will be ready. Can I leave the EU for the USA on my American Passport Name 2, it does not have a stamp of arrival in the EU. I do have documents for all of the name changes, the process, the pareja, the residency but the permiso de soggiorno is still in process and will be canceled because it took longer than the passport.

I can fly from either Barcelona where I am now or from Italy, I just want to do this legally. Does anyone have any advice or experience they can share?

Comment: You need the US passport for the US anyway. Do you have an Italian carta d'identita? That would serve as proof of EU citizenship, when the nationality field states italian.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I leave the EU for the USA on my American Passport Name 2

Yes.

> it does not have a stamp of arrival in the EU.

It doesn't matter; you are an Italian citizen.  Bring the document that you received when you "received citizenship."  When you show that, they will not be interested in your passport stamps.

> the permiso de soggiorno is still in process and will be canceled because it took longer than the passport.

The permesso di soggiorno is irrelevant anyway because, as an Italian citizen, you do not need permission to live in Italy.

It's not clear from your question whether you have a Spanish residence permit.  If you do, it is also no longer relevant because you are an Italian citizen, but it would probably be simpler to go through exit controls showing your US passport and the Spanish residence card, which should cause the border officer not to care about your stamps (including an utter lack of stamps).

It does not matter whether you leave the Schengen area from Spain, Italy, or any other country.